# android sql DB Adapter keeps crashing

Tags: android, sql, adapter

I use the following code to query a database using an adapter

```
db = new DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();
    String strname = roomid;
    Cursor c = db.getAsset(strname);
    if (c.moveToFirst())        
        DisplayContact(c);
db.close();
```

Problem I have is in the class I am using it I get the error

The constructor DBAdapter(SubsamplingScaleImageView) is undefined

the only thing that stops this error is putting NULL in the ()
This however when run crashes the app with a null pointer exception

Can anyone help mean so that I can understand what I need to define to be able to run my query?

If I insert the above code in my main activity it works perfect but the class im using it in is set as follows

public class SubsamplingScaleImageView extends View implements OnTouchListener {

Any help Appreciated

Mark

UPDATE
TRIED THE FOLLOWING BUT STILL GIVES NULL POINTER EXCEPTION

```
    this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
    db = new DBAdapter(this.context);
    db.open();
    String strname = roomid;
    Cursor c = db.getAsset(strname);
    if (c.moveToFirst())        
        DisplayContact(c);
    db.close();
```

Thanks

Mark

Comment: You probably need to give it a Context, which your SubsamplingScaleImageView is not.

Comment: Thank you for that any idea how. im very new to this The is a class not a activity

Comment: db = new DBAdapter(context); works but still crashes that app sayin null pointer exception. context is set using public SubsamplingScaleImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Since SubsamplingScaleImageView is not a context class, you need to provide it with a context. You are apparently obtaining the context in SubsamplingScaleImageView class with the following:

```
Context context;
SubsamplingScaleImageView(Context context) {
    this.context = context; // this is the context you need to pass - not an instance of the ImageView class
}
```

So now, do the following:

```
db = new DBAdapter(context);
```

You should not use getApplicationContext() unless you really know what you are doing. Also at this time, I am assuming that you are passing in the activity or a context you obtained in the activity while calling the SubsamplingImageView constructor.

Comment: Sunil the constructor already has that in it in the form public SubsamplingScaleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr);
        this.context = context;
    } when I call it using db = new DBAdapter(context); it still gives me a null pinter exception

Comment: full code of class here https://www.dropbox.com/s/tsahec4yy9rxw75/SubsamplingScaleImageView.java?dl=0    im having the error at public void finditem(String roomid){